# Equivalent resistance when there is only one terminal?

Tags: resistors, circuit-analysis

How would one go about finding the equivalent resistance when there is only one terminal given? Like the picture below: (Where the squiggly lines are resistors, and the 3 parallel vertical lines represents ground)

[image]

Comment: Ground can be assumed to be the other terminal; you have to calculate the resistange from the terminal to ground.

Comment: So in this case I can just connect both of the grounds to say another terminal B, and pretend that my two terminals are AB?

Comment: Why label it B and not ... GND?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your circuit, I just put names and values for resistors. The triangle at the bottom of the circuit represents ground.

R1 & R2 are connected in parallel because the upper terminals are wired together and the other terminals are connected to ground (Which means they are connected to each other in the same time). If you connect any thing else to ground, it is also connected to the terminals of R1 and R2.

When you connect resistors in parallel, you get an equivalent resistor according to the equation:

1/Req = 1/R1 + 1/R2 + 1/R3 + 1/R4 + ....

In our case,

1/Req = 1/6 + 1/3

Req = 2 ohms  ( this is the equivalent resistor of R1 and R2 only )

The above calculations means that you can remove both R1 and R2 from the circuit and put one resistor of 2 ohms instead of them.

So, let's imagine that there is only single resistor rather than R1 and R2. that single resistor has two terminals, one of them is connected to ground and the other one is connected to R1.

Therefore, R1 is connected in series with the combination of (R2 and R3) because one terminal only of R1 is connected to the combination and the other terminal of R1 is not connected to the combination.

If you have some resistors in series, The equivalent resistance is calculated according to the equation:

Req = R1 + R2 + R3 + ...

In our case,

Req = 2 + 10 = 12 ohms ( this is the total or the equivalent resistance of the circuit)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f53EOg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Voltage is a potential.
Eg the voltage between two points in a circuit is the potential between them.

Whenever you are asked to measure the voltage at a single point in a circuit it is assumed that this is between that point and ground.

So in your case the equivalent resistance would be the combination of all three resistors.